# What is the asymptotics of $gf_2(S_n)$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, asymptotics, symmetric-groups, finitely-generated

Suppose $G$ is a finite group. Let's define $n$-th generating fraction of $G$ as $gf_n(G) := \frac{|\{(a_1, ..., a_n) \in G^n| \langle a_1, ..., a_n \rangle = G\}|}{|G|^n}$.

What is the asymptotics of $gf_2(S_n)$?

The only thing that I managed to determine is that:

$$\frac{n! - 1}{(n!)^2} \leq gf_2(S_n) \leq \frac{3}{4}$$

The lower bound follows from $\frac{3}{2}$-generatedness of symmetric groups. The upper bound follows from the fact that $S_n$ has a subgroup of index $2$.

However, both those bounds are very crude and I would be interested to see something better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An asymptotic result is that $$gf_2(S_n)\to\frac34$$ as $n\to\infty$, proven in [15] in the paper below.
More information can be found in [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0021-9800(70)80017-5).

Comment: Isn't Dixon's result that this tends to $3/4$?

Comment: @verret Yes, but we have to divide it by two as the definition of $gf_2$ is unordered pair and the probability in the paper should be regarded as ordered.

Comment: This is wrong, in both cases the pairs are ordered.

Comment: Thanks for correction.